# How to configure TinyMCE to add more info about widget magento 2

Tags: widget, tinymce, magento2

How can I add more info about magento 2 widget in TinyMCE, like title, or another field? Now only widget type is visible, but I want to concatenate widget type with widget title, or if is possible on hover widget type in TinyMCE, show widget title.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The widgets are encoded in

> lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentowidget/editor_plugin.js:125

I can change from here the information that appears on the editor.

[image]